# ASP.NET Core MVC Binding Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, data-binding

I am trying to develop a simple blog app for learning ASP.NET Core 8 MVC. Category and Post Models are linked between many-to-many relationships. When I try to edit categories in multi-select, I can't see any category data on the PostController side.

PostController Edit Post endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid id, [Bind("Id,Title,Content,CreateAt,IsPublish,Categories")] Post post){
        if (id != post.Id){
            return NotFound();
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(post.Categories.Count()); // 0 value

        if (ModelState.IsValid){
            try {
                _context.Update(post);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PostExists(post.Id)){
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else{
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(post);
    }
```

PostController Post Get Endpoint

```
// GET: Post/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid? id){
    if (id == null){
        return NotFound() 
    }

    var post = await _context.Posts.Include(p => p.Categories).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
    ViewBag.Categories = _context.Categories.Select(r=>new SelectListItem {Value=r.Id.ToString(),Text=r.Name}).ToList();

    if (post == null){
        return NotFound();
    } 
    return View(post);
}
```

Post Edit Page:

```
@model BlogApp.Models.Post
<div class="form-group mt-3">
     @foreach(var category in @Model.Categories){
          <span> @category.Name </span>
     } //for print selecting categories...
     <select multiple="multiple" class="form-select" id="multi_select" asp-for="@Model.Categories" asp-items="(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, There is always a Mr. Down Veto :-)

Comment: You should just bind to a single view model.  Create Post class object with all the properties you need... (your asp-fors will then be like: asp-for="Post.Categories") I believe a multiple select will come through as an array, so probably List<int> Categories.   It's also safer to bind to view model and then process explicitly.  (In this case check to be sure this user can modify this post... the user could modify the form sent to include another Post's primary key)

Comment: Ok I get you. I will update the question, but not work. I just forgot to undo all the code that trying new statements before preparing codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly below statement is added to the Post Model:

```
public class Post
{   
    [NotMapped]
    public List<Guid> SelectedCategoryIds { get; set; }
}
```

Post Controller is edited like below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid id, [Bind("Id,Title,Content,CreateAt,IsPublish,SelectedCategoryIds")] Post post){
    if (id != post.Id){
        return NotFound();
    }
        
    Console.WriteLine(post.SelectedCategoryIds);

    if (ModelState.IsValid){
       try {
            var existingPost = await _context.Posts.Include(p => p.Categories).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == post.Id);
            existingPost.Title = post.Title;
            existingPost.Content = post.Content;
            existingPost.CreateAt = post.CreateAt;
            existingPost.IsPublish = post.IsPublish;

            existingPost.Categories = _context.Categories.Where(c => post.SelectedCategoryIds.Contains(c.Id)).ToList();
            _context.Update(existingPost);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException){
            if (!PostExists(post.Id)){
                return NotFound();
            }
            else{
                throw;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(post);
}
```

View Page Edit like this:

```
<div class="form-group mt-3">
    @foreach(var category in @Model.Categories){
        <span> @category.Name </span>
    }
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-select" id="multi_select" asp-for="@Model.SelectedCategoryIds" asp-items="(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is solution but system did not allow to mark yellow tick during 24 hours...